# Как лучше всего сохранять большое количество связанных между собой данных в android-приложении?

Tags: android, sql, календарь

Создаю приложение, в котором можно записывать, чем ты и когда занимался. Настало время добавить сохранение данных, но не могу найти достаточно информации по этому вопросу.

Мне нужно сохранять список дней, у каждого из которых есть список дел, а у каждого дела название, описание, время начала и конца. Лучшее, что я придумал - это использовать SQLite записывать только конечные данные (название, описание и тайминги), и давать им уникальные id, состоящие из даты (10000000 - 99999999), номера дела (00 - 99), и типа (название/описание/время конца/начала) (00 - 99).

Насколько грамотной является такая реализация? Есть ли варианты получше ил недочеты в моей? Насколько хорошо приложение будет работать, если в базе будут храниться данные за несколько лет по ~10 ячеек в каждом дне?

```
2018.09.21 00 00 (201809210000) = "Программирование" - название первой ячейки 21 сентября 2018 года.
2018.09.21 00 01 (201809210001) = "Создавал базу данных" - описание первой ячейки 21 сентября 2018 года.
2018.09.21 00 02 (201809210002) = "18:00" - время начала первой ячейки 21 сентября 2018 года.
2018.09.21 00 03 (201809210003) = "21:00" - время конца первой ячейки 21 сентября 2018 года.



2018.09.21 01 00 (201809210100) = "Кино" - название второй ячейки 21 сентября 2018 года.
2018.09.21 01 01 (201809210101) = "Хроники Риддика" - описание второй ячейки 21 сентября 2018 года.
2018.09.21 01 02 (201809210102) = "21:10" - время начала второй ячейки 21 сентября 2018 года.
2018.09.21 01 03 (201809210103) = "23:30" - время конца второй ячейки 21 сентября 2018 года.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это будет 365 записей на год. Проблемы с производительностью могут начаться в районе 1000 лет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вашего приложения база данных может содержать одну таблицу, с пятью столбцами: `ID, Название, Описание, Время начала и Время конца`. При этом ID может задаваться с помощью timestamp начала события (если события уникальны и мы не даем пользователю задавать для разных событий одно и тоже время начала), а время начала и время конца лучше задавать датой, а не как у Вас через строку время и брать дату из ID. Говоря о производительности, действительно, только сильно большое количество записей может повлиять на производительность. Исходя из ваших расчетов получается 365 (дней) * 10 (записей в день) = 3650 записей в год, что значительно на производительность не повлияет Главное, грамотно организовать работу с базой данных и не делать CRUD операций в основном потоке.

P.S. Обратил внимание на FloatingActionButton на скриншоте, обычно, делают просто плюсик, без вписывания его в окружность.

Comment: Решил задачу до вашего ответа немного по-другому, но все равно спасибо за ответ.